# Reestructurar login para que el mensaje de error se muestre en la misma pagina

Tags: php, html

me gustaría saber como puede reestructurar este codigo. Ya que no puedo hacer que el mensaje de error ocurra en la misma pagina correctamente, si lo hago, y hago un login exitoso, se clona el index.php con la id del usuario.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!-- Inicio -->
<head> <!-- Logo, menu, el css, etc -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos\login.css">

<style>
#caplock{display:none}body{background-image:url(imagenes/fondo_une.jpg)}form{padding:12px;margin:0}
</style>

</head>

<body> <!-- Aqui ira todo lo demas-->
<center><h1>Bienvenido al formulario de iniciar sesión</h1></center>
<h3>Nota: Es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, por favor escriba de manera consistente. Por ejemplo: "hola" no es igual a "HOLA" u "HoLa"</h3>

<br></br>
<div id="caplock" style="none">El bloqueo de mayúsculas está activado</div>

<form method="POST" action="revisar.php" target="_top"> <!-- Se comunica con revisar.php que hace el login en si-->
<label for="uname"><b>Nombre de usuario:</b></label>
<input type="text" onKeyPress="isMayus(event)"  placeholder="Escriba su nombre de usuario" name="nombre" id="nombre" required></input>

<label for="psw"><b>Clave:</b></label>
<input type="password" onKeyPress="isMayus(event)"  placeholder="Escriba su clave de usuario" name="clave" id="clave" required></input>

<input type="submit" id="Entrar" class="floated" onclick="MyFunction()" value="Entrar"></input>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
<button type="Reset" id="reset" class="floated" onclick="MyFunction()">Cancelar</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunction() { 
var audio = new Audio('audio/click.mp3');
audio.play();
}

var x = document.getElementById("caplock"); //Detecta si esta escribiendo en mayusculas y muestra esto o no
function isMayus(input){
kCode=input.keyCode?input.keyCode:input.which;
sKey=input.shiftKey?input.shiftKey:((kCode==16)?true:false);

if(((kCode>=65&&kCode<=90)&&!sKey)||((kCode>=97&&kCode<=122)&&sKey))
{
    x.style.display = "block";
}else{ 
    x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

El codigo php en si, en revisar.php

```
<html>

<head>

<style>
body{
body{background-image: url("imagenes/fondo_une.jpg")}
}
</style>
</head>

<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba'); //Datos de la base de datos

$nombre = $_POST['nombre']; //Obtener datos
$clave = $_POST['clave']; //Obtener datos

$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $nombre); //Evita SQL injection
$clave = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $clave);  //Evita SQL injection

$clave = md5($clave); //Convierte la clave en md5

$query = "SELECT * from usuarios WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND clave = '$clave' ";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); //Agarra los datos de la fila

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$res =  "Error en usuario y/o contraseña!";

 if($row["nombre"]){ //Revisa si todo salio bien
    $res = '';
    $_SESSION['id']= $get2['id'];
    $_SESSION['Cargo']=$row['Cargo'];
    $_SESSION['nombre']=$row['nombre'];

    header("Location:index.php?id=$id"); //Inicia la sesion
}else{
echo $res;
echo '<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Haga click para volver a la pagina anterior</a></div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar ajax para enviar la petición, así al pulsar el botón evitaras que te cree un clon y los cambios se harán en la misma pagina.

Pruebe a sacar el cogido php a otro fichero y en el boton Entrar , que ejecute una funcion javascript de este estilo:

```
function Entrar() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("caplock").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "NOMBRE_ARCHIVO_PHP", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Funciono, gracias

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Shredder? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde y te dará 2 puntos de reputación). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!